Unable to Connect ROS 2 Controller to Webots Instance from Docker Container
I'm trying to run a ROS 2 application inside a Docker container and simulate it using Webots on the host machine. (On Mac OS)
I tried to run ROS 2 in a Docker container and then simulate it with Webots on the host.
This is the setup:
Dockerfile:  FROM cyberbotics/webots:latest ...
The Controller:
    vehicle_driver = WebotsController(
        robot_name="silicia2",
        parameters=[
            {"robot_description": robot_description_path},
        ],
        protocol="tcp",
        ip_address="192.168.64.1",
        port="1234",
        respawn=True
    )

However, when I try to run it in the Docker container (after: docker run --rm --network="host" --platform linux/amd64 -it core), and then execute ros2 launch core_simulation autonomous_driving_docker.py, i get the following error:
ros2 launch core_simulation autonomous_driving_docker.py ip_address:=192.168.64.1 port:=1234 [INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-11-06-20-56-29-410256-docker-desktop-5937 
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO 
[INFO] [webots_controller_silicia2-1]: process started with pid [5938] ... [INFO] [estimated_state_pub-5]: process started with pid 
[5946] [INFO] [visualizer-6]: process started with pid [5948] [webots_controller_silicia2-1] Cannot connect to Webots instance, retrying for another 50 seconds... ...

- Webots is running in the Host
- Adress and Port is correct
This is strange because the demo file from this documentation works: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/running-extern-robot-controllers?tab-os=macos
Why might the ROS 2 controller in Docker be unable to connect to the Webots instance on the host, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve this?
It would be great if someone could provide some help. :)

Have you read through From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?  Using a VM-based setup like Docker Desktop, host networking typically doesn't do what you want (and it's not usually a best practice in any case).  You may find it easier to run both parts in Docker, or neither, than to repeatedly cross in and out of container space.
